# C# MS- Saving image in a the similiar path

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have been trying to save an image into my MS Access database. But because the path is way too long for a regular text for MS, it did not work out.

eg: `C:\users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg`
I am thinking if its possible to save the file name (Desert.jpg)and put the file path (`C:\users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures`) in the coding, since all pictures are in the same file.

The coding below is how I upload the image from C#, and save the path link from  `txt_image.Text` into MS Access which is set to hyperlink for now.
Thank you!

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "JPGFiles(*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files(*.png)|*.png|All Files(*.*)|*.*";


        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string picLoc = dlg.FileName.ToString();
            txt_image.Text = picLoc;
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = picLoc;
        }
    }
```